# Make a form submitting both GET and POST

Tags: asp.net-core, post, get, form-submit, razor-pages

I have a page, where I do a search. Then I can make some actions on results of the search.
Here the page:

```
@page "{handler?}"
@model Pricelists.ListModel

<form>
    <div><label><input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" asp-for="OnlyEnabled" /> Only enabled</label></div>

    //all other filters used in the search

    <input type="submit" formmethod="get" asp-page-handler="Search" />

    @if (Model.SearchResult.PaginatedResults != null)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="PageNumber" value="@Model.PageNumber" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="TotalPages" value="@Model.TotalPages" />

        <table>
            <tr>
                //header result
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.SearchResult.PaginatedResults)
            {
                <tr>
                    //result
                </tr>
            }
        </table>

        <label>Page @Model.PageNumber of @Model.TotalPages (Number of records: @Model.SearchResult.Count)</label>
        <input type="submit" formmethod="get" asp-page-handler="Previous" value="<" />
        <input type="submit" formmethod="get" asp-page-handler="Next" value=">" />

        <div>
            <input type="submit" formmethod="post" asp-page-handler="Enable" value="Enable" />
            <input type="submit" formmethod="post" asp-page-handler="Disable" value="Disable" />
            <input type="submit" formmethod="post" asp-page-handler="Delete" value="Delete" />
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

As you can see, either when I do the search or when I change the page, I submit the form using `GET`.
But I would like to make a `POST` submit to modify (enable, disable or delete) the result of the search.

Here the `PageModel`:

```
public class ListModel : PageModel
{
    private const int RECORDS_PER_PAGE = 20;
    private readonly AdminApiClient _client;

    #region Selected Filters
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
    public bool OnlyEnabled { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public long[] SelectedCategories { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string[] SelectedCarriers { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string[] SelectedDepartures { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string[] SelectedArrivals { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    #endregion


    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public PriceListSearchViewModel SearchResult { get; set; }


    public ListModel(AdminApiClient clientFactory)
    {
        _client = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        await this.LoadViewDataAsync();
    }

    public async Task OnGetSearch()
    {
        this.PageNumber = 1;

        await this.LoadViewDataAsync();
        this.SearchResult = await this._client.Pricelists.Search(this.SelectedCategories, this.SelectedCarriers, this.SelectedDepartures, this.SelectedArrivals, this.OnlyEnabled, this.PageNumber, RECORDS_PER_PAGE);

        this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(this.SearchResult.Count / (decimal)RECORDS_PER_PAGE);
    }

    public async Task OnGetNext()
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task OnGetPrevious()
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public async Task OnPostEnable()
    {
        await this.LoadViewDataAsync();
        await this._client.Pricelists.ChangeStatus(this.SelectedCategories, this.SelectedCarriers, this.SelectedDepartures, this.SelectedArrivals, this.OnlyEnabled, this.PageNumber, RECORDS_PER_PAGE, enable: true);
    }

    public async Task OnPostDisable()
    {
        await this.LoadViewDataAsync();
        await this._client.Pricelists.ChangeStatus(this.SelectedCategories, this.SelectedCarriers, this.SelectedDepartures, this.SelectedArrivals, this.OnlyEnabled, this.PageNumber, RECORDS_PER_PAGE, enable: false);
    }

    public async Task OnPostDelete()
    {
        await this.LoadViewDataAsync();
        await this._client.Pricelists.Delete(this.SelectedCategories, this.SelectedCarriers, this.SelectedDepartures, this.SelectedArrivals, this.OnlyEnabled, this.PageNumber, RECORDS_PER_PAGE);
    }
}
```

To semplify I let you see just one GET and one POST method. But, in any case I use same binded properties.

Now, when I make a `GET` submit everything works correctly. But when I make a `POST` submit I get an error `400 Bad request`. I let you see a `fiddler`:

[image]

The http request is what I expected, but obviously not the response.

Any idea?

**EDIT**
I never go in the methods `OnPost*`. It is like the way I have implemented the submit button is wrong. The problem is not the implementation of the `OnPost*` methods.

Thank you

Comment: How can we tell you what is output if you don't show any code.

Comment: I have written the whole cshtml and the related PageModel. Why you say I do not show any code?  `OnGetNext` and `OnGetPrevious` are the same of `OnGetChange` with the only difference about `PageNumber`. Do you want to see the table result? I think there is everything, but if you need more code, tell me what you want to see

Comment: I am sorry , but I can't see any code at PostDelete for example. How could I know why it returns 400 status.

Comment: I have modified the post. However I never go in `OnPostEnable`, `OnPostDisable` and `OnPostDelete`... so the problem is not the implementation of the method.

Comment: You should put more explanations then. Do you have 404 or 400 error?

Comment: 400 Bad request. I have also uploaded an image. From the image the body of the request seems good to me. But the response is 400

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, Separate forms and write a form for each method. or jsut handle it using javascript.

look at this sample:

```
<form id="frm" action="/test" method="post">

<button type="submit">save</button>
```

and script:

```
<script>

setTimeout(function () {

    var frmElement = document.getElementById('frm');
    frmElement.setAttribute('method', 'get')

}, 2000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove form that you have and make a special form for each button

```
<form asp-page-handler="delete" method="post">
     <button class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
</form>
.... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `method="post"` to `<form>`.Example:`<form method="post">`.

I test with your code,when click the inputs with `formmethod="post"`,it will lose `__RequestVerificationToken` in the form data.And after you add `method="post"` to form,it will have a hidden input as the following shows:

[image]

result:
[image]